# Does ScipyImaginaryEvolver in qiskit work independently of ansatz and parameters?

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I am solving a Hamiltonian using imaginary time evolution and I tried it with VarQITE and ScipyImaginaryEvolver available in qiskit. I created a custom ansatz so that the evolved state revolves only between the set of basis states I am interested in. This seemed to work for VarQITE but the classical method shifted to other eigenstates and gave eigenvalues lower than all the eigenstates possible on evolution of my ansatz.
Is this because the script solver just takes the initial state as input and then evolves it in time without caring about the parameters?